# Why can't I center this form input field of type text in html using text-align: center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am learning HTML and I am trying to implement a search bar, but it needs to be centered. I've been googling for about 4 hours, and I can't make it. I have tried a lot of tutorials, but they don't work.

In the button, CSS rule `text-align: center;` works, but in the search bar it doesn't. I am using Bootstrap to help style the web page. Anyway, here is my HTML code:

```css
#search-bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" id="search-bar">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Google Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean you want the text inside the search bar to be centered?

Comment: what do you want to center ? text inside search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I took is different. With CSS, you can add `margin-left: 25%` so that it will move 25% of the body of the element to the right. That way if you set the elemnt width to 50%, it will end up centered.
In this case, this my css:

```
#search-bar {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
#search-bar { 
              display : flex;
              justify-content : center;
              align-items : center;
            }
```

For more details about flex-box styling:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

text-align:center; is not working due to width constraint if you are using bootstrap then you can try using 'ml-auto' and 'mr-auto'

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 mr-auto ml-auto">
  <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" id="search-bar">
</div>
```

or if you wanted to use plain css then you can specify property

margin:0 auto;